# MvcSiteMapProvider not showing breadcrumb as links and routes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I'm facing this problem using MvcSiteMapProvider with ASP NET MVC 5.

Sometimes, When the application is deployed (using the release mode), the breadcrumb links breaks and it isn't showed as it should be, like the images below:

Expected: 
http://s33.postimg.org/oop4ua3tb/breabcrumb_funcionando_mapeamentocampo.png

Broken link 2:http://s33.postimg.org/yjga0i7rj/breadcrumb_mapeamento_de_campo.png

This is the sitemap file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<mvcSiteMap xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/schemas/MvcSiteMap-File-4.0 MvcSiteMapSchema.xsd">

  <mvcSiteMapNode title="Home" controller="Home" action="Index">
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Processos" controller="Processo" action="Index" key="Processo">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Alterar Processo" controller="Processo" action="Alterar" preservedRouteParameters="Id" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Importar Processos" controller="ImportarProcessos" action="ImportarProcessos">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Histórico de Importação" controller="ImportarProcessos" action="HistoricoImportacao" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Histórico de Inconsistências" controller="ImportarProcessos" action="HistoricoInconsistencia" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Meus Dados" controller="Conta" action="MeusDados" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Parâmetros Gerais" controller="ParametroGeral" action="Index" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Regras de Validação" controller="RegraValidacao" action="Index" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Mapeamento dos Campos" controller="MapeamentoCampo" action="Index" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Módulos Externos" controller="ModuloExterno" action="Index" key="ModuloExternoPai">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="ConfigurarModulo" controller="ModuloExterno" action="ConfigurarModulo" preservedRouteParameters="Id" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Usuários" controller="Usuario" action="Index" key="Usuario">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Registrar" controller="Usuario" action="Registrar" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="AlterarUsuario" controller="Usuario" action="Editar" preservedRouteParameters="Id" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Lista Negra de Senhas" controller="ListaNegraSenha" action="Index" key="ListaNegraSenha">
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Registrar" controller="ListaNegraSenha" action="Registrar" />
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="AlterarSenha" controller="ListaNegraSenha" action="Editar" preservedRouteParameters="Id" />
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Relatório de Log" controller="RelatorioLogger" action="RelatorioLogger" />
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Sobre" controller="Home" action="Sobre" />
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMap>
```

This is the code in the view used to render the Breadcrumb:

```
   <div class="breadcrumb">
            <span>@LabelsResources.BreadCrumbsMessage @Html.MvcSiteMap().SiteMapPath()</span>
        </div>
```

We've tried to deploy the sitemap file within the solution folder, but it didn't work too.

Have someone faced the same problem and know how to fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Best guess is that the files in the `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/` folder that `MvcSiteMapProvider` uses to render the HTML (Namely `SiteMapPathHelperModel.cshtml` and `SiteMapNodeModel.cshtml`) are not included in the deployment or have been modified in some way that renders the key of the node instead of a hierarchy of links.